# Repository is offline on Centos and cant update dnf

Tags: apache, cloudflare

I finished installing my server and while doing that I used a lot of time the command `dnf update` and nothing went wrong. Now, I tried using the command `dnf update` and I see this error:

```
[root@li1135-74 ~]# dnf update
mod_cloudflare Packages                          62 kB/s | 854  B     00:00
Error: Loading repository 'modcloudflare' has failed
```

I installed `mod_cloudflare` previously and it was working fine. However it may be with problems (maybe its repository is offline?), so how do I use `dnf update` but skip this `mod_cloudflare` error? I just want to update based on other repositories. Is there a parameter on `dnf` that "skips" repositories with errors?

EDIT: I am using CENTOS 8 with LAMP.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to temporary disable this repo

```
dnf config-manager --set-disabled modcloudflare
```

do the update

```
dnf update
```

and then enable it if you want

```
dnf config-manager --set-enabled modcloudflare
```